# What is the difference between sort data.txt | uniq -q and just 'uniq -q'?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, uniq

I understand that it sorts and that output is used to find out the unique statement in the file. I also feel that uniq -u should print every unique statement in the file.

```
uniq -u data.txt
```

Output for this statement is:

```
MsxcvOe3PGrt78wpZG2bBNF5wfXpZhET
L0nxAwlfV9V3J5onKIT8KYQ9InTcQ7yE
4c7EsUtqLnLR9hiepV5EQVhdMgyi8onL
1drBmDT7PYS7hVgoTWkJSjUZUK7ZAIAa
L0nxAwlfV9V3J5onKIT8KYQ9InTcQ7yE
78rgduVcLZjLzZmooObdaN541MKV6IfQ
x0bga8Oxz5lgM8k52HrYy4ez7XJI0lM0
irGm6F73sbUrFhHukhp6JXgMQyLxJTz1
```

However when I run

```
sort data.txt | uniq -u
```

Output is:
`UsvVyFSfZZWbi6wgC7dAFyFuR62324324324`

I am not able to understand why the first statement prints a list when there is only one line output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uniq utility reads the specified input file and compares only adjacent lines and writes  a copy of each unique input line to the output file.

For example if your data is:

```
1
1
2
5
4
1
```

Output of `uniq -u data`  would be:

```
2
5
4
1
```

Whereas output for `sort data | uniq -u` would be as follows:

Output of sort:

```
1 
1
1
2
4
5
```

And when this is passed to `uniq -u` the output would be:

```
2
4
5
```

Answer (score 3):

Uniq only compares adjacent lines. Therefore uniq -u on the following input will not detect duplicates and print out everything

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

If you call sort first, you will get a sorted list which is deduplicated correctly. You probably have some duplicates later in the file